# How to use interface as a generic parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

I have a generic class:

```
class JobDetails<IJobRequirement>{}
class SpecialRequirement: IJobRequirement{}
```

I'm unable to assign the values of type `JobDetails<SpecialRequirement>` to variables of type `JobDetails<IJobRequirement>`. Is this possible in C# or am I missing something basic ?

Comment: Can you please post all your code?  That first class seems to have a generic type named `IJobRequirement` which is not the same as setting the generic type to an interface with that name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally `Foo<A>` and `Foo<B>` do not share a common ancestry. They share a common generic type definition, but that does not mean they are assignable even if `public class B : A`.

You seem to be looking for Co- and Contravariance. A mechanism for generics in C# that lets you define compatibility between different types. However this only works for generic interfaces.

For example

```
public interface IJobDetails<out TRequirement>
   where TRequirement : IJobRequirement
{
    TRequirement Requirement { get; }
}

public class JobDetails<TRequirement> : IJobDetails<TRequirement>
{
    public TRequirement Requirement { get; set; }
}

public void Test()
{
    IJobDetails<IJobRequirement> a = new JobDetails<SpecificRequirement>();
}
```

However using the modifier `in` or `out` limits whether you can use the type **only** as a return value **or** a method argument.

This is the reason why you an assign `IEnumerable<B>` to `IEnumerable<A>` if `public class B : A` because `IEnumerable` is declared as `IEnumerable<out T>`.

For further information I recommend reading the following Blog: http://tomasp.net/blog/variance-explained.aspx/

Comment: @ivymike, check this as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces

Answer (score 2):

You can put [constraints on Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

```
interface IJobRequirement
{ }

class SpecialRequirement : IJobRequirement
{ }

class JobDetails<T> where T : IJobRequirement
{ }
```

Comment: Hi @junkangli, doesn't JobDetails<IJobRequirement> automatically imply this ?

Comment: No, it does not. Check the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters